# Make Product Y buyable only if Product X is bought

Tags: magento-1.9

I am making an e-commerce website for an eye-wear client. They have three types of products, namely - Frames, Sunglasses and Lenses. Frames and Sunglasses can be bought freely but Lenses can only be bought if a customer buys any Frame, or some specific sunglasses with power available. Customer can choose to buy these eye-wears with or without Lenses.

When choosing a product, they will have the option to choose from different types of lenses. Lenses won't be available either in catalog or in the search.

What do you think is the best solution for this case? I am already aware of [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40867/buy-y-only-if-you-buy-x), but is there a better solution using Bundled/Grouped/Configurable products? How would you go about solving this?

**Update**

As per @Marius's suggestion, I have implemented the grouped products. It works flawlessly in front-end. Screenshot:
[image: Front End]

This is exactly what I wanted. However, I am facing some trouble in the backend now. For some reason, I am not being able to enter Stock Quantity  for bundled products.  Please refer to the screenshot below:

[image: No field to enter stock amount]

and the grid shows zero stock, yet the product is available in front-end.
[image: Grid shows 0 stock]

If I could somehow specify the stock amount in backend, it would have been a perfect solution! Thanks for the help so far.

Answer (score 2):

I think bundle should work. I don't know the problems you experienced with it and why doesn't it fit for you, but this is how I would do it.
First of all all lenses should have the visibility "not visible individually". This will hide them from the catalog and search. But you probably already did this.

Then have your Frame products as bundle products with an option called 'Lenses'. This option can be of any type (radio, select, multiselect, checkbox) but don't make it required. And as selections for the lenses put all the products compatible with the product you are adding.

In theory this should work nicely. But I may be missing something.

Comment: Thanks for the answer man. Let me check  the options you have mentioned. I will get back to the thread tomorrow and accept the answer if it solves my problem :)

Comment: Please see my updated question. :)

Comment: @noc2spamツ I don't think this is possible. For some reason that escapes me the qty field is only available for non composite products. There is this line `<?php if(!$this->getProduct()->isComposite()): ?>` above the qty field in the admin inventory template. Sorry I overlooked this when recommending this approach. It may not be suitable for you. But you can try to manipulate the inventory template and allow qty fields for bundle products and see what happens.

Comment: thanks a lot. I will be overriding the core templates because your solution is exactly what I was looking for in the front-end. I will post my code once I get everything working. Hopefully, this question will help others who are facing such problems.